# Python openpyxl save have TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I using openpyxl(Version: 2.6.2), on ubuntu16.04 the code can execute success:

```
wb.save('filename.xlsx')
```

but on win10(same openpyxl version), some error like below:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 397, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 276, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 76, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 216, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer = WorksheetWriter(ws)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 55, in __init__
    next(self.xf) # start generator
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 286, in get_stream
    with xf.element("worksheet", xmlns=SHEET_MAIN_NS):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 37, in element
    self._top_element = Element(tag, attrib=attrib, **_extra)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)
```

It also create the filename.xlsx, but is broken file.

Is version issues or some wrong with save?

---

Solve after install lxml:

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code as well? How you make `wb` and the processing you do with it? Might make it easier to debug

Comment: You can submit a bug report with a sample file or code but I suggest you install lxml.

Comment: @razdi I can't save with just load file and save new or create and save new:
 ```wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file1.xlsx')
wb.save('file2.xlsx')```
but on my ubuntu will not get error.

Comment: @CharlieClark thank for help, is my lxml on other path, now reinstall lxml can save it correct.

Comment: The error comes from the et_xmlfile library that mimics the behaviour of lxml's xmfile file function. and I suspect that it lxml installed on the Linux machine but not on Windows.